# Why do I have to go through index.php while routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, path, routes, fedora

I am learning routing in php.I came across this problem and I don't know how to solve it.
Here is my index.php file.

```
<?php
$database = require "Core/bootstrap.php";
$router = new Router;
require "routes.php";
require $router->direct('contact');
```

My routes:

```
<?php
$router->define([
    '' => 'Controller/index.php',
    'about' => 'Controller/about.php',
    'about/culture' => 'Controller/about-culture.php',
    'contact' => 'Controller/contact.php'

]);
```

Finally the Router class:

```
<?php
class Router {
    protected $routes = [];
    public function define($routes){
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }
    public function direct($uri){
        if(array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes)){
            return $this->routes[$uri];
        }}}
```

In the above example I have 'contact' as my predefined route.I open 'localhost' and it takes me to 'contact' page but if I write 'localhost/contact',I get '404 not found'.Instead if i go through 'localhost/index.php/contact' everything's fine.It's the same for other routes.
I know the problem here is (i could be wrong) absolute and relative path.I am using fedora 28,I searched .htaccess but I didnt understand what to do.
I would appreciate a little explanation rather than just an answer.

Comment: It is not directing your index page to contact. It is just including your contact page. You have to parse uri on index page and should pass variable in direct function if you have anything after (index.php/).

Comment: If you just want to remove index.php from url then create .htaccess file in root and past these lines..  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Do you mean I have to add these lines to my .httpd.conf  or do i have to make another file ?    I tried both but dosn't change anything.I can't restart server when i add these lines to httpd.conf

Comment: no. dont add these lines to .httpd.conf. Create a new file name it '.htaccess' and past these lines and save it where your index.php file is.

Comment: It gives me 500 internal server error..